# How can I change the Python interpreter in virtual environment (Ubuntu 18.04LTS)?

Tags: python, python-venv, virtual-environment

I always used Anaconda on Windows so far and could set up an environment while choosing which exact Python to use. E.g. `conda create -n myEnvName python=3.7`

Now, I want to familiarize with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and use basic Python environments.

So I followed these steps:

1. Created folder in my `home = ~/.venvPython`

   - (a) I think I already had a 2.7 and 3.6 by default on the OS.
   - (b) I do not remember for sure, I think I had to do this `sudo apt-get install python3-venv`.
2. Created environment this way after CD'ing to .venvPython folder ran this: `python3 -m venv venv1BigDataPgm2`
3. `source ~/.venvPython/venv1BigDataPgm2/bin/activate`
4. Command `python --version` says: `Python 3.6.9`

Running `whereis Python` shows this:

```
rohit@rohitUb18043LTS:~$ whereis python
python: /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3.6-config /usr/bin/python2.7-config /usr/bin/python3.6m-config /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python3.6m /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/lib/python3.8 /usr/lib/python3.7 /usr/lib/python3.6 /usr/lib/python2.7 /etc/python3.6 /etc/python /etc/python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python3.6 /usr/local/lib/python2.7 /usr/include/python3.6 /usr/include/python3.6m /usr/include/python2.7 /usr/share/python /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz
```

My doubts:
Can I specify a Python version directly while creating the environment like with *conda*?
How do I change this to some other interpreter instead of the 3.6.9?
Do I have to manually install a different Python first, then point it somehow?

Please guide me. Thank you.
Rohit

Comment: Try using a shebang. In unix a shebang is used to select the interpreter. It is the first line of your program and looks like this: `#!usr/bin/env python3` if you are using python 3.X

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/1674444/2771562 answer your question? The python version specified has to be installed on your os.

Comment: This exact scenerario is my main reason for using `pyenv` instead of other `venv` providers. With `pyenv` you can control the exact version for each env quite easily. I would check it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell the [`venv` standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) appeared in *Python 3.3* and was never *backported* to *2.7*.

`venv` can only create virtual environment for its own version of the interpreter and the virtual environment directory can not be moved to a different location or be renamed. Python *3.foo* can not create a virtual environment for *Python 3.bar*. So it is best to pick the wanted interpreter right from the start.

Since, as shown by the output of `whereis python`, you seem to already have multiple Python interpreters already installed, you should be able to do something like the following:

```
$ /path/to/python3.3 -m venv /path/to/my/venvs/venv33
$ /path/to/python3.8 -m venv /path/to/my/venvs/venv38
```

There seems to be a way to change the Python interpreter associated with a virtual environment (I have not tested it, not sure what the limitations are):

```
$ /path/to/python3.8 -m venv --upgrade /path/to/my/venvs/venv33
```

Alternatively use [*virtualenv*](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/) which seems to offer a bit more flexibility, but is probably less efficient (its next major release, [*virtualenv 20*](https://discuss.python.org/t/virtualenv-20-0-0-beta1-is-available/3077), should bring a lot of improvements though).

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu and other Debian-based systems generally ship whichever Python version was current and deemed sufficiently tested when the release was published; after that, only security updates which preserve the version number but add patches are released (so you might get 3.6.9-123security4 instead of 3.6.9-5 or whatever was current when the release was cut).

If you want to run a specific Python version on one of these platforms, see if you can find an Apt source which provides this version for your system (Ubuntu has a soft underbelly of unofficial PPAs of various repute; Debian has `backports`) or install it from source yourself. There are add-ons like `pyenv` which let you do this rather easily, safely, and transparently.

There may also be an existing package which gives you a particular newer version; for example, you can do `apt install python3.7` and `apt install python3.8` on Ubuntu 18.04, but there are no packages for 3.5 or 3.9. Try `apt policy python3.7` to see which specific minor version is available from the Ubuntu package archive.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to that is to always specify the python version you wish use when running a script.

```
python3.6 test_script.py
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when I'm on Linux and don't need a specific python3 version, I create native python3 environments.

```
python3 -m venv myenv
source myenv/bin/activate
```

But if I need a specific python3 version, I do:

```
python3.9 -m venv myenv
source myenv/bin/activate
```

To use a specific python3 version with native environments, you have to install that version using the native package manager (eg. apt).